# Gnome terminal not opening

Tags: gnome-terminal

The gnome terminal has recently stopped working for me (happened on 19.10 I think but have since upgraded to Focal Fossa development branch where it is still occurring). It does not open when clicked on (the tab appears with loading spinner but then quickly disappears) and when I run `gnome-terminal` in x-term (which thankfully still works) I get the following error:

```
~:20:02:23$ gnome-terminal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1: undefined symbol: pcre2_serialize_get_number_of_codes_8
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as x-term is far from ideal and I'm running out of ideas of what to do.